# Ratios of Gaussian integrals with a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: integration, gaussian, matrix-inverse, path-integral

Cross-post from MSE

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118128/ratios-of-gaussian-integrals-with-a-positive-semidefinite-matrix

Generally speaking, I’m wondering what the usual identities for Gaussian multiple integrals with a positive definite matrix become when the matrix is only positive semidefinite.
I could not find anything about this in the literature, any reference is welcome.

For instance, if ${\mathbf{A}}$ is positive definite, then we have

$\mathbb{E}{x_i} = \frac{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }} = {\left( {{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right)_i}$

If ${\mathbf{A}}$ is only positive semidefinite, do we have

$\mathbb{E}{x_i} = \frac{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }} = {\left( {{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right)_i}$

where ${{\mathbf{A}}^ + }$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of ${\mathbf{A}}$ ?

Of course, both integrals become infinite with a psd matrix. But this does not imply that the ratio itself is infinite. The situation looks similar to Feynman path integrals in QM and QFT: we can only talk about ratios of path integrals since both integrals are infinite because they are infinite-dimensional. But the ratio is finite, otherwise path integrals would not exist. Do we have the same kind of infinity cancellation phenomenon with ratios of finite-dimensional Gaussian integrals with a psd matrix as with e.g. infinite-dimensional Gaussian path integrals?

P.S., following Carlo's comment: the second formula with the pseudo-inverse holds with very high probability, that's an experimental fact. Indeed, when used in applications, it finally gives meaningful and useful results, everything works fine. It is possible that the formula holds only in special cases, including my own. But my own ${\mathbf{A}}$ and ${\mathbf{J}}$ are pretty random, so that the formula is likely to hold without conditions. But proving it under suitable conditions would be great too.

Comment: if $A$ and $J$ are diagonal, with $A_{ii}=0$, the pseudo-inverse would give you $(A^+J)_i=0$; would that make sense? If instead I take $A_{ii}=\epsilon$ and then take the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ I would get infinity.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker J is a column vector Carlo.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The second formula with the pseudo-inverse holds with very high probability: indeed, when used in applications, it finally provides meaningful and useful results, everything works fine. It is possible that the formula holds only in special cases, including my own. But my own A and J are pretty random, so that the formula is likely to hold in full generality, without restrictions. But proving it under suitable conditions would be great too!

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I first developed a probabilistic code working with multivariate Gaussian distributions with pd covariance matrices. Then I realized that I need to work with psd covariances matrices. In this case the distributions are NOT absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure but absolutely continuous w.r.t the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on the codomain, with covariance matrix given by the pseudo-inverse. So I just replaced 1) the dimension by the rank 2) the determinant by the pseudo-determinant and 3) the inverse by the pseudo-inverse everywhere in my calculations..

Comment: @CarloBeenakker... This includes the formula above but many other formulae, e.g. block formulae for the determinant and the inverse (Schur complement). I know that block formulae for the pseudo-det et the pseudo-inverse work only under special algebraic conditions that are fulfilled in my own case because everything works at the end. So, perhaps there are some conditions for the formula above, but it basically works.

Comment: To make sense of this equation, one first has to regularize the left-hand side. This is certainly possible; however, note that formally the left-hand side is invariant under $A\mapsto UAU^T, J\mapsto UJ$ using the substitution $x\mapsto UX$, whereas the right-hand side is not. Essentially, you use the scalar product on your vector space for the regularization, which is only invariant under this substitution if $U$ is orthogonal.

Comment: @BertramArnold Yes, some kind of regularization is required. I'm sorry, but I don't see how the substitution ${\mathbf{Y}} \mapsto {{\mathbf{U}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{X}}$  (to be consistent with other substitutions) leaves the left-hand side invariant. What about ${{x_i}}$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker In my code, the pd case arises when my problem has Dirichlet boundary conditions and the psd case corresponds to the same problem without Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Consider e.g. a 1st order or 2nd order derivative regularization matrix R obtained by a finite differences scheme on [0,1]. If we have Dirichlet boundary conditions e.g. f(0)=f(1)=0, then R is pd. If we don't R is psd. By the principle of maximum entropy, a pd R gives a Gaussian prior distribution with covariance matrix R. If R is psd, nothing works (H=-inf). But R must be psd, the prior must not have a pdf under the Lebesgue measure and moments because it must be invariant up to translations for the 1st order derivative and up to affine functions for the 2nd order derivative.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Pure regularization (but Tikhonov) Gaussian priors without Dirichlet boundary conditions are necessarily singular. That's the reason why I replaced the inverses by the pseudo-inverses. It works perfectly but it would be much better if someone could prove the generalized Gaussian identity. I could not find anything about that, that's surprising, because singular priors are fundamental in regularization theory.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker To finally answer your remark: yes, the pseudo-inverse is not continuous. But so is the Gaussian integral, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very partial answer.

**Theorem** : if ${\mathbf{A}}$  is positive semidefinite and ${\mathbf{J}} = {\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$, then $\mathbb{E}{\mathbf{x}} = {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$ , provided we allow ourself to cancel out terms like $\frac{a}{a}$  even if $a$   is infinite.

**Proof** : recall one of the usual proofs of the identity

$\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{T}}}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  = \frac{{{{\left( {2\pi } \right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}}{{\sqrt {\left| {\mathbf{A}} \right|} }}{e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}$

for a positive definite matrix ${\mathbf{A}}$ .

Substitute ${\mathbf{x}}$ by  ${\mathbf{y}} = {\mathbf{x}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}$

${{\text{d}}^n}{\mathbf{x}} = {{\text{d}}^n}{\mathbf{y}}$

$ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}} =  - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right)^T}{\mathbf{A}}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right) =  \\
   - \frac{1}{2}\left( {{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{y}} =  \\
  \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}} \\ $

Therefore

$\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  = {e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{y}}}  = \frac{{{{\left( {2\pi } \right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}}{{\sqrt {\left| {\mathbf{A}} \right|} }}{e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}$

Then, by the Leibniz rule/Feynman trick

$ \frac{{\partial \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}} = \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {\frac{{\partial {e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}}}{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  = \int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  =  \\
  \frac{{{{\left( {2\pi } \right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}}{{\sqrt {\left| {\mathbf{A}} \right|} }}\frac{{\partial {e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}}}}}{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}} = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} \frac{\partial }{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}  \\  $

Hence

$\mathbb{E}{x_i} = \frac{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{x_i}{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }}{{\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}} }} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial }{{\partial {{\mathbf{J}}_i}}}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}} = {\left( {{{\mathbf{A}}^{ - 1}}{\mathbf{J}}} \right)_i}$

Now, for a positive semidefinite matrix  ${\mathbf{A}}$, substitute ${\mathbf{x}}$ by  ${\mathbf{y}} = {\mathbf{x}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$

$   - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}} =  - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right)^T}{\mathbf{A}}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{y}} + {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}} \right) =  \\
   - \frac{1}{2}\left( {{{\mathbf{J}}^T}\underbrace {{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }}_{{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }}{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{Ay}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}} \right) + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{y}} = \\
  \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}} - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}} \right){\mathbf{y}} \\  $

The integral

$\int\limits_{\,{\mathbf{x}}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{y}}^T}{\mathbf{Ay}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{y}}} $

now is infinite. But it is not a big deal because it cancels out in the Leibniz rule/Feynman trick above (please tell me).

Therefore, the term ${{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}} \right){\mathbf{y}}$ , where ${\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}$  is the orthogonal projector on  $\ker {\mathbf{A}}$, is the main obstruction against the generalized formula.

So, if  ${{\mathbf{J}}^T}\left( {{\mathbf{I}} - {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{A}}} \right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow {\mathbf{J}} = {\mathbf{A}}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$ then

$\int\limits_{{\mathbb{R}^n}} {{e^{ - \frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{x}}^T}{\mathbf{Ax}} + {{\mathbf{J}}^T}{\mathbf{x}}}}{\text{d}}{\mathbf{x}}}  \propto {e^{\frac{1}{2}{{\mathbf{J}}^T}{{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}}}$

and the generalized formula

$\mathbb{E}{\mathbf{x}} = {{\mathbf{A}}^ + }{\mathbf{J}}$

follows by the Leibniz rule/Feynman trick.

Perhaps this condition is fulfilled with my own ${\mathbf{A}}$  and ${\mathbf{J}}$, I need to check.